# Have browser cache embedded iframe css and js files

Tags: jquery, html, caching, iframe

Say I have file `main.html`.  In it I have an `iframe` which references `sub.html`. There is also a button on `main.html` which when clicked reloads `sub.html`.  `sub.html` uses jQuery/HTML5, and hence references a lot of js and css files.

Is there a way have the browser cache these js and css files on the initial load and not reload them when the button to refresh the `iframe` is clicked?

Comment: It should do this by default, assuming you haven't disabled caching in your browser.

Comment: Ideally, you would configure the webserver to send the proper freshness information http headers, and then the browser would do this automatically. Most webservers are configured to direct browsers to do a partial form of caching. Do you have the ability to alter webserver config? Otherwise, if the config needs to be altered, you only choice is going to be ugly hacks where the subpage grabs data from the parent, which is tedious.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan - In checking our server logs it is not.  I agree - most of the literature seems to be tailored around how to prevent caching; not enabling it.  This occurs with Chrome and Safari on iPad.

Comment: @rambocoder - I will check that out.  It is actually a Indy Server using Delphi (totally custom).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was not sending the proper headers to instruct the browser to cache the css/js files.